# How do i access to a json value with 5 variables with the same name

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

I'm making a NSFW filter and i need the results of the analysis, i need to verify if Pºrn and Hºntie are higher than 0.7, but i dont know how to access the percent value because its all the same

i first declare it with this:

```js
let pred = await model.classify(image)
```

and returns something like this:

```
[
  { className: 'Drawing', probability: 0.8663265705108643 },
  { className: 'H*ntai', probability: 0.13287211954593658 },
  { className: 'Neutral', probability: 0.0006077145808376372 },
  { className: 'P*rn', probability: 0.0001762539177434519 },
  { className: 'S*xy', probability: 0.000017335718439426273 }
]
```

and because they're the same i dont know how to detect the values of probability of only pºrn and hºntie to check if one of them are higher than 0.7, i hope this doesn't get marked bad.

Comment: It's an *array* of objects that you need to search through. You do process it as object instead of string, don't you?

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is find using [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) each entry for `'Porn'` and `'Hentai'`. Then you can compare the probability of each one:

```js
const porn   = pred.find(r => r.className === 'Porn');
const hentai = pred.find(r => r.className === 'Hentai');

// The Math.max is another way of doing:
// if (porn.probability > 0.7 || hentai.probability > 0.7) { ... }

if (Math.max(porn.probability, hentai.probability) > 0.7) {
  // do something
}
```

Also if the function `model.classify()` is under your control, you could make it return an `Object` instead of an `Array` like this:

```js
{
  drawing: { probability: 0.8663265705108643 },
  hentai:  { probability: 0.13287211954593658 },
  neutral: { probability: 0.0006077145808376372 },
  porn:    { probability: 0.0001762539177434519 },
  sexy:    { probability: 0.000017335718439426273 }
}
```

and access each probability like so:

```js
if (pred.hentai.probability > 0.7 || pred.porn.probability > 0.7) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the probability of the `P*rn` class name like this:

```js
if (results.find(result => result.className == 'P*rn').probability > 0.7) {
  // some stuff
}
```